# controlling tooltip formatting for JavaFX WebView

Tags: javafx, webview

I know that formatting of "native" tooltips (rendering of the HTML `title` attribute upon mouse-hover) is up to the browser -- but if my team is building a custom JavaFX application with a [`WebView`](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/web/WebView.html) component as the browser, **is there any way to tweak the styles of the tooltips in Java?** (color/font/max width/etc)

This would necessarily be "out-of-band" from the standpoint of the rendered HTML/CSS/Javascript, unless `WebView` provides hooks to let the rendered content dictate tooltip styles.

---

This is driving me nuts; the color and font seem to be easily tweakable via css as documented in https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html:

```
.tooltip {
    -fx-background-color: rgb(128, 64, 0);
    -fx-border-color: rgb(128, 128, 128);
    -fx-font-family: Garamond;
    -fx-font-size: 30pt;
}
```

But there doesn't seem to be any way to specify `max-width`, and for the life of me I can't figure out where the tooltip logic actually happens (namely: when user hovers over HTML element with `title` attribute, the attribute value is displayed as a tooltip) despite looking in the OpenJDK source (e.g. [com.sun.javafx.webkit.WebPageClientImpl](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/openjfx/8/master/rt/file/f89b7dc932af/modules/web/src/main/java/com/sun/javafx/webkit/WebPageClientImpl.java) )

Comment: You may do by programing like that: `tooltip.setPrefSize(120, 60);`